# getHeight returns real height when summoned in main but returns 0 when summoned from another class

Tags: java, swing

When I use getHeight() and getWidth() from my main, right after frame.pack(), I get the true height/width value. But when I use them in my other class, it doesn't work.
I already tried to organize my main differently (because many suggested it in other similar questions) and it ended up getting a bit messy and nothing changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rubik's Cube Solver");
    frame.setVisible(true);     
    frame.setSize(1200,1200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    frame.setLayout(layout);
    Rubiks_Cube cube = new Rubiks_Cube();
    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    JButton scramble = new JButton("Scramble");
    JToggleButton solver = new JToggleButton("Solve");
    scramble.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cube.scramble();
        }

    });
    solver.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cube.solver();
        }

    });
    top.add(scramble);
    top.add(solver);

    frame.add(top, layout.PAGE_START);

    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JPanel green = new JPanel();
    JPanel red = new JPanel();
    JPanel blue = new JPanel();
    JPanel orange = new JPanel();
    JPanel white = new JPanel();
    JPanel yellow = new JPanel();

    bottom.setVisible(true);
    green.setVisible(true);
    red.setVisible(true);
    blue.setVisible(true);
    orange.setVisible(true);
    white.setVisible(true);
    yellow.setVisible(true);

    bottom.add(green);
    bottom.add(red);
    bottom.add(blue);
    bottom.add(orange);
    bottom.add(white);
    bottom.add(yellow);

    green.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    red.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    blue.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    orange.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    white.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    yellow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));

    green.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    red.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    blue.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    orange.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    white.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    yellow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    green.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    red.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    blue.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    orange.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    white.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    yellow.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200,200));

    frame.add(bottom);
    frame.pack();

    green.add(new paintCube("green", cube));
    red.add(new paintCube("red", cube));
    blue.add(new paintCube("blue", cube));
    orange.add(new paintCube("orange", cube));
    white.add(new paintCube("white", cube));
    yellow.add(new paintCube("yellow", cube));

    System.out.print(green.getHeight); //<===== returns the real height

}}
```

This is my other class.

```
public class paintCube extends Rubiks_Cube {

private String facecolor = null;
private Rubiks_Cube cube = new Rubiks_Cube();

public paintCube(String color, Rubiks_Cube cube) {
    facecolor = color;
    cubelayout = cube.getCubeLayout();
}

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        int a = 0;
        switch (facecolor) {
            case "green": a = 0; break;
            case "blue": a = 2; break;
            case "white": a = 4; break;
            case "orange": a = 3; break;
            case "yellow": a = 5; break;
            case "red": a = 1; break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
            int b = cubelayout[a][i]/10;
            switch (b) {
                case 0: g2.setColor(Color.GREEN); break;
                case 1: g2.setColor(Color.RED); break;
                case 2: g2.setColor(Color.BLUE); break;
                case 3: g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE); break;
                case 4: g2.setColor(Color.WHITE); break;
                case 5: g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW); break;
            }
            int j = cubelayout[a][i]%10;
            switch (j) {
                case 0: g2.fillRect(0, 0, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 1: g2.fillRect(super.getWidth()/3, 0, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 2: g2.fillRect((super.getWidth()/3)*2, 0, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 3: g2.fillRect(0, super.getHeight()/3, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 4: g2.fillRect(super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 5: g2.fillRect((super.getWidth()/3)*2, super.getHeight()/3, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 6: g2.fillRect(0, (super.getHeight()/3)*2, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 7: g2.fillRect(super.getWidth()/3, (super.getHeight()/3)*2, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
                case 8: g2.fillRect((super.getWidth()/3)*2, (super.getHeight()/3)*2, super.getWidth()/3, super.getHeight()/3); break;
            }
        }

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            g2.drawLine((super.getWidth()/3)*i, super.getHeight(), (super.getWidth()/3)*i, 0);
            g2.drawLine(super.getWidth(), (super.getHeight()/3)*i, 0, (super.getHeight()/3)*i);
        }
        System.out.println(super.getHeight()); //<==== returns 1 everytime
        }}
```

I'm new to this so please correct other mistakes if you see any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main(), you are getting the width/height of green, which is a JPanel whose size you have specified.

In paintCube, you are getting the width/height of the paintCube that has been added to green. It is laid out by the default layout manager of JPanel, which is a FlowLayout, since you did not specify a layout manager. You did not specify a size for that component, so its size is zero.

Change the layout manager of green, etc., to  BorderLayout and add the paintCube to it using BorderLayout.CENTER, so it will expand to the size of the parent (green).

BTW, you should follow Java convention and name your class PaintCube, not paintCube.